# Authentication of a .net website from a java web

Tags: java, .net, c#-4.0, authentication

There is a link from a JAVA web application to a .NET web application. How can I authenticate the .NET web application in a simple way to make sure the user is authenticated somehow.
Thanks.

Comment: Not much explanation here but to me the best way to do so would be to call a remote service from your Java webapp.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without writing another piece of authentication API. I just need a basic authentication.

Comment: One more time, with the details you give I just can tell : it depends on your existing services. How can I know ? ^^

Comment: There is a Java web app which has a link to a .NET application which passes information in the query string say: https://www.abc.com/Index.aspx?uid=3456 Once user clicks on this link the .NET application opens up. The Java web app has a different authentication and is not shared with .NET web app both residing on different servers. I was thinking of encrypting the query string or have some kind of basic authentication as the .NET web app is on a secured server. Thanks.